# Рисование кривых линий от блока до бока

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, изображения, html

Всем привет!
Может кто находил библиотеки jquery для рисования кривых полос как на картинке ниже отрисованы рельсы (от блока к блоку, с изгибами, полоса - картинка)? Что-то ничего придумать не могу. Может подскажете в каком направлении копать? хочется выводить блоки на страничке и от блока к блоку красивая полоса в виде дорожки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте canvas и adobe flash к примеру для создания первого, чтобы не руками писать

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но flash не могу т.к. ориентируюсь на любые устройства в т.ч. и на мобильные/планшеты, а в них есть сложности с флешем.

Comment: опять же - на канвасе мне нужно указывать точки по которым это всё будет. Если блоки будут двигаться в зависимости от расширения / масштаба - всё съедет. Нужен автоматический расчет видимо.